# React - Filtering objects in store causes recursion/infinity loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I use redux store in my react application to store data such as my expenses.

Now I use these expenses in one of the components to calculate a TODO badge count to show like so

```
const [badgeValue, setBadgeValue] = useState(0);
const expenses = useSelector(({ expenses }: RootState) => expenses.items);

useEffect(() => {
    const setBadge = async () => {
        const badgeNumber = await calculateRequestBadgeNumber(expenses);
        setBadgeValue(badgeNumber);
    };

    setBadge();

    return () => setBadgeValue(0);
}, [expenses]);
```

This works as expected. Now however, I'm experiencing a weird side effect when I want to filter out deleted expenses like so:

```
 const expenses = useSelector(({ expenses }: RootState) => 
     expenses.items.filter((expense: Expense) => !expense.deleted)
 );
```

This results in an endless loop of useEffects being called. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

As with most things involving React hooks, the identity of the objects involved (e.g. what you test for with `===`) is important here. When the identity of `expenses` differs from the last render, your effect is triggered.

---

#### Selector A

This hook returns the `items` property of the `expenses` property of your Redux state. If the state doesn't change, neither will the identity of the `items` property.

```js
const expenses = useSelector(({ expenses }: RootState) => expenses.items);
```

---

#### Selector B

This returns the result of calling `filter` on the items array. The filter method returns a brand new array.

```js
const expenses = useSelector(({ expenses }: RootState) => 
     expenses.items.filter((expense: Expense) => !expense.deleted)
);
```

---

What you're observing is Selector B returning a new value each time the component renders, thus the effect is triggered too often.

Now - [`useSelector` *can* cache its return value](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates) to reuse if the state hasn't changed but *only* if the identity of the selector function you pass to it remains the same. You can ensure this by naming the selector in the module scope as opposed to the component.

```js
const filteredExpenses = ({ expenses }: RootState) =>
  expenses.items.filter((expense: Expense) => !expense.deleted);

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [badgeValue, setBadgeValue] = useState(0);
  const expenses = useSelector(filteredExpenses);
  useEffect(() => {
    const setBadge = async () => {
      const badgeNumber = await calculateRequestBadgeNumber(expenses);
      setBadgeValue(badgeNumber);
    };

    setBadge();

    return () => setBadgeValue(0);
  }, [expenses]);
  return <StuffToRender />;
};
```